# Display dropdown options as expanded buttons - PHP JS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

We are modifying a Wordpress site with a php/js search form that uses a dropdown selector. How could I display the selectable options as expanded buttons rather than having a dropdown? Currently there are 2 options you can select 'For Sale' and 'For Rent' but we would like to see these without having to click on the dropdown. Ideally remove the dropdown altogether but keep the related functionality. I am new to php and we are overriding plugin code here so the cleanest and simplest options would be most appreciated. If we can get away with not touching the JS that would be excellent.

The initial code is below just let me know if you need anything else and I'll reply straight away. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php if(isset($search_fields['status'])) { ?>
            <div class="iw-field iw-display-table-cell field-for-status">
                <?php
                    $field = $search_fields['status'];
                    $all_term = get_terms(array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'iwp_status',
                        'hide_empty' => true,
                    ));

                    if (count($all_term) > 0) {
                        $args = array(
                            'name' => 'iwp_status',
                            'options' => array(
                                '' => $field['name'],
                            )
                        );
                        if (isset($data_filters['iwp_status'])) {
                            $args['value'] = $data_filters['iwp_status'][0];
                        }
                        foreach ($all_term as $key => $status) {
                            $args['options'][$status->term_id] = $status->name;
                        }
                        echo Inwave_Helper::renderIWSelect($args, false);
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are calling `echo Inwave_Helper::renderIWSelect($args, false);` by the end of Your function. As the methods name suggests, it is rendering selectbox. You have to either switch / extend the method or use your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am very new to php though so modifying anything myself is tough. Is it possible to simply change the line above so instead of rendering a dropdown it renders buttons with the same options? Or would this simply fail? Apologies if this is a v. noob issue

Comment: I think it is definitelly possible, you can echo a html string (populated using $args).

Comment: Do you think you could give me an example to try? Or is it not that simple? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell. I would first try to find out what is this Inwave thing (a plugin? part of a theme?) and what's its API.

Comment: It's a wordpress site using an inwave theme and inwave plugins. There is a live version of the theme online at http://www.roohool.com The dropdown we are trying to use is the Status box to the left of the search bar. Is this any help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with that. You should probably try to contact inwave theme support.